# What is Dirac talking about here?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, time, history

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xJzrU38pGWc&ab_channel=mehranshargh

> "I might say that my recent work has been very much concerned with Einstein's general relativity and I believe that the Times and Distances which are to be used in Einstein's General Relativity are not the same as the Times and Distances which are provided by the atomic clocks" (at around [9.18](https://youtu.be/xJzrU38pGWc?t=560))

My understanding is that we don't think that atomic time is different from time in a relativistic sense and Atomic clocks would behave exactly the same way as any other clocks. If I remember correctly the most accurate test of gravitational time dilation uses atomic clocks.

Did anything come out of his work in this direction?

Comment: I had a quick look, and there seems to be no indication of what aspects Dirac is talking about, except that they are to be "solved" by radar signals bounced off Mars.  It appears that soon after that comment, the interviewer brings GR into the conversation, as if previously they were only discussing SR.  Pretty unsatisfying interview, sadly.

Comment: @m4r35n357 They were initially discussing symmetries in physics and then they moved on to GR and Dirac seem to think that Time kept by atomic clocks shouldn't be taken as same Time that we talk about in GR. Maybe I am misunderstanding him but it seem wrong.

Comment: Sure.  It doesn't come across as a particularly "educational" discussion.  I'm not sure what it is supposed to be!

Comment: @benrg well that satisfies _my_ curiosity!